# Java loop execution error

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class comp
{
int a,b,i,k,l;
comp()
{

    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number");
    a=s.nextInt();
    b=s.nextInt();
    divide(a,b);

}
public void display(int[] b)
{
    for(i=0;i<b.length;i++)
        System.out.println(b[i]);
}
public void divide(int e,int f)
{
    int[] st=new int[20];
    //System.out.println(e);
    i=0;

    if(e>0)
    {
        l=e%10;
        e=e/10;
        st[i]=l;
        i++;

    }
    this.display(st);

    //return st;

}



}
class km extends comp
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    km m=new km();      



}
}
```

The if loop in the divide function is getting executed only once.It should execute exactly to the number of digits of the number.I am just trying to convert integer to an array.

Comment: debugger is your friend.

Comment: That `if` block in `divide` (which doesn't seem to properly named) will only extract the last digit of `e`.

Comment: "_The for loop in the divide function_" There is no for loop in the divide function.

Comment: It's if loop sorry my bad.

Comment: There's no such thing as "`if` loop". Replace `if` -> `while`. Then [delete] :-)

Comment: If statement is not a loop. If gets evaluated only once. You might need to put it inside of a for loop.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yeah it works now why does if fail?

Comment: @user1613360 because `if` is a conditional, not a loop :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks please post it as an answer.

Comment: @user1613360 No way I'd post something like this as an answer :):):) Just delete the question, and pretend that this whole "if loop" incident never happened.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I did a real life lol at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not repeating because you have a if (e > 0).

Maybe it should be a while (e > 0) ?

Answer (score 1):

if will only evaluate once, then move on to the rest of the code. while will continue process the code until the condition is false.

Change your `if` to a `while`.

```
while(e>0)
{
    l=e%10;
    e=e/10;
    st[i]=l;
    i++;
}
```

However take note, your current code is going to display your integer backwards